# Installing an apk present in data directory

Tags: java, android, uri

I'm trying to install an apk file present in internal/external storage.
This is my code:

```
final String fileuri = "file://" + absolutePath;
Log.v("FILE_BROWSER", "File to be installed: " + Uri.parse(fileuri).getPath());
final Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileuri), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

The apk file is sucessfully installed if the file is present on external storage. Eg. `/mnt/sdcard/MyApp.apk`

But if the apk file is present on internal storage (Eg. /data/data/com.myapp/files/MyApp.apk) then the installation fails. Error message is: `Parse Error: There is a problem parsing the package`

One solution can be copying the file to SDCARD and then installing it. But, in the scenario where SDCARD is unavailable, this trick will not work.

Any help on this guys? How can I install an apk present on internal storage directory if SDCARD is unavailable?

Comment: Make sure when your .apk file is placed in internal storage then its have WORLD_READABLE permission.

Comment: I'm implementing a file browser equivalent application. And if my application can see the file, then the file is WORLD_READABLE i guess.

Comment: No, its not necessary.. If your application write a file in PRIVATE mode then only your application can read and write it. Not any third party or other application do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this your .apk file has to `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` permission.

I am doing this to write .apk file in my application's Internal Storage

```
String outFileName = path+"/<Application_Name>.apk";
OutputStream myOutput = openFileOutput("<Application_Name>.apk", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

And then to install it,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path+"/<Application_Name>.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Here path is  `path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();`

And this works fine in my case..

Comment: first i tried setting the file permission to MODE_WORLD_READABLE, as initially suggested by user370305. Didn't work then. After that I changed `Uri.parse("file://" + absolutePath)` to `Uri.fromFile(new File(absolutePath))` and now it works fine. Thanks a lot.